# How to fetch particular fileds alone in django?

Tags: sql, django

I have two models `Model Faculty & Model Courses`.

Each course can have one faculty, but a faculty can multiple courses ( thats how it works ).

Now on template i need to display as :

```
Faculty 1:
   -- course1
   -- couse2
Faculty 2:
   -- course1
   -- course2
```

Check the image

[image]

So as of now there is an `One to one` relation between Course and Faculty ! By this i can find faculty, but how to split faculty wise ?

My first question : Do i need to create `Many to One` between faculty & course ?

My Second Question: I just need to show course name & faculty name ( for that am fecthing all the course contents from data base, how to avoid that )

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Comment: I understand, i dont know how to explain as its bit complicated :( @jarlh

Comment: It's even more complicated to us when you can't explain it.

Comment: okay, let me remove it :( My question is, I need to show courses, faculty wise ! So for just showing course name and faculty name  am fetching all the course contents ! So asking whats the best and effecient way do , so that i dont need to fetch all extra contnets

Comment: I have updated the question, hope you can understand now @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a standard One to Many relationship. Usually the best way to handle this is with a simple foreign key.

```
class Faculty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class Course(models.Model):
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='courses')
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

You can then access the courses for each faculty in the template like this (assuming you are passing `faculties` in the context to the template and `faculties` is a queryset of the Faculty model):

```
{% for faculty in faculties %}
    {{ faculty.name }}
    {% for course in faculty.courses.all %}
        {{ course.name }}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```